# Xamarin.iOSのWebViewにおけるJavaScriptとC#の連携方法

Tags: javascript, ios, c#, xamarin

Xamarin.iOSでWebViewアプリを開発しております。
JavaScriptとC#の連携方法について教えてください。

JavaScriptとC#の連携を必要としており、
現在はJavaSciptからC#メソッドをコールする方法として、
URLスキームを利用し、C#メソッドを実行しております。
　
※AppDeligateでURLオープンをフックし、「hoge://」の場合はC#メソッドを実行
　以下のサイトを参考に実装
　http://furuya02.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/07/17/011823

ただし、この方法ですとiOSのアクセスガイドを実行した際に、
URLスキームの実行がブロックされてしまいます。

アクセスガイド中に使える、JavaScriptからC#メソッドをコールする方法はないでしょうか？
もしくは、アクセスガイド中にURLスキームを利用する方法はあるのでしょうか？
　
何卒、よろしくお願い致します。
　
　
＜開発環境＞
IDE: VisualStudio for Mac 7.4.2
iOS: 11.3
macOS: 10.13.4
もし情報が不足しておりましたら、ご指摘ください。

Comment: ご掲載のリンク先は`UIWebView`を使用したものですが、`WKWebView`でよければ、[こんな記事](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62280/call-c-code-from-javascript)が見つかりました。自分では試していないのでアクセスガイド中に使えるかどうかなどわかりませんが、今からでも`WKWebView`に切り替えられるなら試してみられてはどうかでしょうか。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/121725

Comment: @OOPer さん　ありがとうございます。（お返事遅れてすみません）　別の方法ですが、対応できました。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。できましたらその「別の方法」、回答の形で投稿していただけると今後同じことでお悩みの方の役に立つかと思います。是非ともよろしくお願いします。